# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates is never getting called

Tags: android, google-maps

Instead of LocationManager, I have use LocationServices method to get current gps location and location updates.

this is the code:

```
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();//PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000*30*1);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000*30*1);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);
    }
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
        {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
    //Place current location marker
     latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
     lat= location.getLatitude();
     log=location.getLongitude();
     trim_check_location_change(lat,log);
     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
     markerOptions.position(latLng);
     markerOptions.title(""+s);
     markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
     mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
     //move map camera
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
     CurrentLocation = latLng;
```

}

As I move from from one place to another, blue marker moves accordingly.
however onlocationchanged method never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed fused location api demo application and utility pack here.

[General Utilities](https://github.com/abhishek-tm/general-utilities-android)

Try it if useful for you. To get location using fused location api, you just have to write following snippet...

```
new LocationHandler(this)
    .setLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Get the best known location
    }
}).start();
```

And if you want to customise it, simply find documentation here...

https://github.com/abhishek-tm/general-utilities-android/wiki/Location-Handler

**Update**

I've written a sample code according to your need, try this one...

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import in.teramatrix.utilities.service.LocationHandler;
import in.teramatrix.utilities.util.MapUtils;

/**
 * Lets see how to use utilities module by implementing location listener.
 *
 * @author Khan
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Marker marker;
    private LocationHandler locationHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Obtaining an instance of map
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        this.locationHandler = new LocationHandler(this)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(10000)
                .setLocationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.locationHandler.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (marker == null) {
            marker = MapUtils.addMarker(map, latLng, R.drawable.ic_current_location);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14), 500, null);
        } else {
            marker.setPosition(latLng);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationHandler != null) {
            locationHandler.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == LocationHandler.REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            locationHandler.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I checked your github code. I changed distance to 1mtr and i moved for some meters.I used a toast message to indicate location change.  But onLocatioChanged still not working.

Comment: @cgeek GPS will not recognise this distance which is covered in just some meters. Go outside and watch. It should be minimum 10-20 meters.

Comment: Included your github code. Worked perfectly.. Thank you.